# Variable using decimal comma instead of decimal point

Tags: excel, vba, internationalization, decimal, number-formatting

I have been using Excel VBA for a while now and I have come across a problem that I have never encountered before. I am using someone elses computer that is set up as Polish, so the decimal separator is set to comma. But even when I had my computer set up similarly in the past I did not have any problem.

This current project creates a drawing in Visio.

So,

I have a variable of type double that is calculated as `pgeWidth = 550 / 1.4`

What I would expect is that VBA would calculate `pageWidth = 392.857...` 
However what VBA is doing is `pgeWidth = 392,857...` If I put a break in and check the value of pgeWidth it shows the value with a comma separator. pgeWidth is then set to the page width property in Visio which thinks it should be 392857.... mm wide which obviously gives an error.

Why is VBA using a comma decimal separator instead of a point?

Comment: Excel use the system local settings to format numbers, currencies and times.

Comment: VBA is respecting the regional decimal symbol in its output.  It appears that Visio is not respecting the decimal symbol as being a comma, even though it is defined that way in your Windows Regional settings.  What version of Visio?

Comment: Another thought, from someone not familiar with Visio.  Perhaps you could `Round` or `Truncate` the value.  You may not need to specify the dimension to fractions of a millimeter.  eg.  `pgeWidth = Int(pgeWidth)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass the value further with point, consider converting variable to a string and then replacing comma with point:

```
pgeWidth = replace(CStr(pgeWidth), ",",".")
```